# Access Subversion repository through IBM HTTP Server

Tags: apache, svn, ibmhttpserver

Is possible to access Subversion repository through IBM HTTP Server like we do with Apache HTTPD server?

Can the DAV_SVN modules from Apache be used in IBM HTTP Server?

I like to use IBM HTTP Server to access my subversion repository instead of Apache httpd server. Is this possible? Any suggestions / Help?

Thanks a lot for the help

Cheers,
Prabhu

Comment: Is possible to access the Subversion Repository using WebSphere? Or any other IBM tool?

Comment: Since IBM HTTP Server is built based on Apache, follow the procedure for correct Apache version. It might work. I haven't tried it though. Check IHS and the underneath Apache version using `httpd -V`. It will give you something like `Server version: IBM_HTTP_Server/7.0.0.0 (Win32) Apache version: 2.2.8 (with additional fixes)`

Comment: What do you mean access it? Actually provide the storage  and SVN access for it? Or view its contents with a CGI script?

Either way, it's a bad idea to do this with IHS because it's not likely to be a supported usage. IHS is supported when it's used in a direct and necessary way w/ an IBM product that bundled it.